# Testing for NULL

Tags: vba, excel

If I run:

```
Sub dural()
    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Cells.HasFormula
End Sub
```

It will display *True* if **all** the occupied cells in the worksheet have formulas, and it will display *False* if **none** of the occupied cells in the worksheet have formulas.

However if **some** of the occupied cells have formulas, the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837123.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

says the property will return `Null`

How can I craft a `MsgBox` to display this case ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the IsNull function

You can use a function instead of a Sub so you can test where you called it from.

```
Function dural() As Variant
    dural = ActiveSheet.Cells.HasFormula
    If IsNull(dural) = True Then
        MsgBox "It's null"
    End If
End Function
```

or leave it as a sub

```
Sub dural()
    Dim test as Variant
    test= ActiveSheet.Cells.HasFormula
    If IsNull(test) = True Then
        MsgBox "It's null"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I had never used the `ActiveSheet.Cells.HasFormula` so I learned something new.. Glad to help.